# How to properly debug a cross-compiled Windows code on linux?

Tags: debugging, cross-compiling, mingw32, wine

I have a small piece of Windows code, basically one copied from the [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409(v=vs.85).aspx) but adapted for C++. I can compile it now using one of the methods:

- `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -g hello.cpp -o hello` to produce a native Windows PE32 executable,
- `wineg++ -g hello.cpp -o hello` to produce a `libwine` wrapper pair `hello.exe` + `hello.exe.so`.

All I want now is to start the file in a debugger (`gdb` or an interface to it if possible) and **stop at the entry point `WinMain`**. I'm failing badly at this. What I have tried (NB: in the following, `hello` without extension is, quite unconventially, the Windows executable):

- `wine /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/gdbserver.exe :2000 hello` followed by `target remote :2000` in a local `gdb`: finds no symbols at all, everything is `??` across 10+ stack frames
- `wine /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/gdb.exe hello`: hangs, does not accept any user input on the command line
- `gdb wine` followed by `run hello`: `Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install wine-core-1.9.19-1.fc24.i686`, which I did and the error remains
- `gdb hello.exe.so`: causes a SIGSEGV
- modifying the `hello.exe` script so that it sets the right environment but runs `gdb` in the end: no symbols whatsoever, `??` everywhere
- `winedbg hello` with and without `--gdb`: **gets the farthest so far**, starts with a black console window and lets me step in, but whatever is in my code is still `??`-ed out and `WinMain` (or anything containing that string) is not known
- `winedbg hello.exe` (for the output of `wineg++`): the program loads fully, the debugger hangs waiting for it while it already runs in the background
- running the application and attaching to it in `winedbg`: does not fit the purpose (won't allow me to stop at the entry point) but otherwise works mostly like the last two points (works with the output of `MinGW` but does not show any internals of `hello.exe`, does not work at all with the output of `wineg++`).
- reading tons of official and unofficial tutorials, bug reports, SO questions...

I can't even remember the other combinations I tried. Surely it can't be that hard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems I figured it out. With the compile command line

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -gstabs hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

I can run

```
winedbg hello.exe
```

and in its command line,

```
break WinMain@16
cont
```

The important option was **`-gstabs`** instead of `-g` and no `--gdb` for `winedbg`. I figured out both after reading [this mailing list thread](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2005-January/032558.html), more relevant pieces of information are discussed there.

Note that the bare `winedbg` is seriously impaired when it comes to name mangling and such, but `gdb` won't work (at least not out of the box) for the reasons outlined [in the link above](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2005-January/032558.html).

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to debug programs running under Wine is to run full-featured gdbserver under it. First, the required packages need to be installed, e.g. under Debian:

```
    # apt install gdb-mingw-w64 gdb-mingw-w64-target
```

Then run the program as

```
    $ wine Z:/usr/share/win64/gdbserver.exe localhost:12345 myprogram.exe
```

and, finally, from another terminal/screen window:

```
    $ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gdb myprogram.exe
    (gdb) set solib-search-path ...directories with the DLLs used by the program...
    (gdb) target extended-remote localhost:12345
```

and then debug normally as usual, i.e. with full access to debug information and working breakpoints and so on.

In particular, running `gdbserver` works much better than using `winedbg --gdb` which seems to be quite broken since many years.

Comment: This answer should be the correct answer for 2022.  Your instructions are perfectly clear, and they work for me on Debian stable.

Comment: @VZ. did you compile using wineg++ or i686-w64-mingw32-g++?

in my case gdb connects to gdb server but is unable to load any info about source file...

any suggestions on 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72517177/debug-wine-32bit-c-c-app-in-vscode-using-gdbserver

Answer (score 2):

You can run winedbg --gdb --no-start progra.exe  .And after this you can use Hopper dissansambler and attach to the port you get .