# debug WINE 32bit C/C++ app in vscode using gdbserver

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, cmake, wine

## Problem

Trying to debug win `hello world` app cross compiled using `i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix` in VSCode. But VSCode fails to attach to dbgserver.

## Repo

VSCode project repo is located [HERE](https://github.com/aleksas/vscode-wine-mingw-boilerplate).

## Setup

### Cross compile win app on nix

Compiler is [configured](https://github.com/aleksas/vscode-wine-mingw-boilerplate/blob/master/.vscode/cmake-kits.json#L5-L6) to use `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix` and `i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix` for C and CXX code respectively.

Building cmake project generates `./build/hello.exe` which can be run using command `wine ./build/hello.exe`.

### Attach gdb to gdbserver

As per [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68268087) running gdbserver using command
`wine Z:/usr/share/win32/gdbserver.exe localhost:3456 /workspace/build/hello.exe` and attaching debugger using command `/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gdb --eval-command='target remote 127.0.0.1:3456' /workspace/build/hello.exe`. For convenience sh script [/usr/bin/gdbserver](https://github.com/aleksas/vscode-wine-mingw-boilerplate/blob/master/gdbserver) was added launching `wine Z:/usr/share/win32/gdbserver.exe $@`.

works fine. Debugger loads symbols, prints following output:

```
...
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /workspace/build/hello.exe...done.
Remote debugging using 127.0.0.1:3456
Reading C:/windows/system32/ntdll.dll from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
Reading C:/windows/system32/kernel32.dll from remote target...
Reading C:/windows/system32/kernelbase.dll from remote target...
Reading C:/windows/system32/msvcrt.dll from remote target...
0x7bc51a41 in DbgBreakPoint@0 () from target:C:/windows/system32/ntdll.dll
(gdb)
```

At this point everything looks fine.

### Configure VSCode

To set up VSCode debugger [launch.json](https://github.com/aleksas/vscode-wine-mingw-boilerplate/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json) file was added with [custom paths and parameters to run gdb and gdbserver](https://github.com/aleksas/vscode-wine-mingw-boilerplate/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json#L17-L20) as indicated [HERE](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference).

### Debugging using VSCode

Launching debug configurations initiates a process but doesn't seem to progress to an expected debugging scenario. As soon as debug server launch [timeout](https://github.com/aleksas/vscode-wine-mingw-boilerplate//blob/master/.vscode/launch.json#L15) is reached `Unable to start debugging. No process is associated with this object.` message pops up and debugging stops.

It is worth noting that before timeout is reached running
`/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gdb --eval-command='target remote 127.0.0.1:3456' /workspace/build/hello.exe` attaches debugger to gdbserver process initiated by VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Some gdbserver configs were missing](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/266#issuecomment-259753176)

After changes dbgserver running wine app works fine. Boiler plate project for 32 bit wine app acn be found [HERE](https://github.com/aleksas/vscode-wine-mingw-boilerplate).